# Inserting multiple $_Post arrays into a database

Tags: php

how can I add `$_POST['wmeet']` into the auto INSERT or should I do a separate UPDATE. I want all 6 `$_POST['wmeet']` values to go into m_wmeet in format "ce1 sf1 sm1" a single space in between each value

```
if (is_array($_POST['add']))
          foreach ($_POST['add'] as $key => $value) 
          $_POST['add'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));

if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
          foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) 
          $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));

        function dbSet($fields, $source = array()) {
            $set='';
            if (!source) $source = &$_POST;
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                if (isset($source[$field])) {
             $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($source[$field])."', ";
                }
            }
            return substr($set, 0, -2);
        }

$fields = explode(" ", "m_user m_pass m_email m_date m_ip m_type m_country m_place");
$query_mem = "INSERT INTO social_members SET ".dbSet($fields, $_POST['add']);

            mysql_query($query_mem);
```

Comment: Can't you just do `$value = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);`

Comment: @KristerAndersson then do I do and Update to apply it or can it be added to my INSERT?

Answer (score 1):

One way to try to take advantage of similar syntax between INSERT and UPDATE is to use the implode method mentioned by @KristerAndersson combined with REPLACE INTO. You'll have to have a primary key that is part of your insert or else a unique key for this to work. Since REPLACE INTO shares the same column syntax as INSERT INTO you can just use it and get your UPDATES along with your INSERTS. Keep in mind that REPLACE INTO deletes the old row and inserts a new one so the record key will change.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if (is_array($_POST['add']))
   foreach ($_POST['add'] as $key => $value) 
      $_POST['add'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));

   if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
         $_POST['add']['m_wmeet'] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(implode(' ',$_POST['wmeet'])));

    function dbSet($fields, $source = array()) {
        $set='';
        if (!source) $source = &$_POST;
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            if (isset($source[$field])) {
         $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($source[$field])."', ";
            }
        }
        return substr($set, 0, -2);
    }

 $fields = explode(" ", "m_user m_pass m_email m_date m_ip m_type m_country m_place m_wmeet");
 $query_mem = "INSERT INTO social_members SET ".dbSet($fields, $_POST['add']);
 mysql_query($query_mem);
```

Comment: I kind of see where you're going with this.

Comment: I like this better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

this is what i've put together from the comments/answers ... which one would work?

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
   foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) 
   $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
   $wmeet = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);
```

or does it need to be something like

```
$_POST['wmeet'][$key] = 
mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet'])));
```

and then the insert code... would something like this work?

```
$query_mem = "INSERT INTO social_members 
    SET ".dbSet($fields, $_POST['add']. ", m_wmeet=".$wmeet);
```